# requestAnimationFrame - Moving circle

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, requestanimationframe

I been struggling with this for a while now and I can't seem to get it right.

What I'm trying to do is, have a circle which is a **div** float around inside a container which is also a **div**. I know this can be achieved with a **canvas**, but I want do this with **divs**

This is what I got to so far:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="box">
    <div class="circle" id="circle"></div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .box {
        background-color:yellow;
        height:300px;
        width:500px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .circle {
        background-color:blue;
        height:50px;
        width:50px;
        border-radius:50%;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    var floater = function(){

    requestAnimationFrame(floater);

    var circles = document.getElementById('ball');        
    circles.style.left = (((Math.sin(new Date() / 1000) + 1)) * 500) + "px";
    circles.style.bottom = (((Math.sin(new Date() / 1000) + 1)) * 300) + "px";

}

floater();
```

The Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6nvg8pv0/4/

Comment: This is what I' trying to achieve with divs, [http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/9v3nu/](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/9v3nu/)

Answer (score 0):

For starters you'd have to restrict the coordinates to be inside the box

```
mycircle.style.left = Math.min(450, (((Math.sin(new Date() / 1000) + 1)) * 500)) + "px";
mycircle.style.top = Math.min(250, (((Math.sin(new Date() / 1000) + 1)) * 300)) + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can restrict the motion to be inside the box by changing the value you multiply the sin result with

```
  mycircle.style.left = (((Math.sin(Date.now() / 1000)) + 1) * 225) + "px";
  mycircle.style.top = (((Math.sin(Date.now() / 1000)) + 1) * 125) + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you add 1 to sinus  ?  You get a value from 0 to 2 so the circle does twice the width and height. Take the absolute value with Math.abs. Remove the +1.